# Add columns in CSV file using windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

i have a csv file with pipe (|) delimiter like below. Column header defines by 6 columns but rows value has 7 columns.

```
Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5|Column 6
Value 1 |Value 2 |Value 3 |Value 4 |Value 5 |Value 6 |0
Value 11|Value 12|Value 13|Value 14|Value 15|Value 16|0
```

So i try to make new column with windows batch script.

Here is my code :

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Row=0
( for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=|" %%A in (BAT0071.csv) do (
    Set /A Row+=1
    If !Row! lss 2 (Rem new header
      echo %%A^|%%B^|%%C^|%%D^|%%E^|%%F^|IgnoreLast
    ) Else (Rem insert duplicate values
      echo %%A^|%%B^|%%C^|%%D^|%%E^|%%F^|%%G
    )
  )
) >"BAT0071.tmp"
move /y "BAT0071.tmp" "BAT0071.csv"
PAUSE
```

The problem is if all rows value filled then its fine, but example value 3 in first row empty then the structure changed like below.

```
Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5|Column 6|IgnoreLast
Value 1 |Value 2 |Value 4 |Value 5 |Value 6 |0|
Value 11|Value 12|Value 13|Value 14|Value 15|Value 16|0
```

How to make empty value still in position?

**Expected result**

```
Column 1|Column 2|Column 3|Column 4|Column 5|Column 6|IgnoreLast
Value 1 |Value 2 |Value 3 |Value 4 |Value 5 |Value 6 |0
Value 11|Value 12|Value 13|Value 14|Value 15|Value 16|0
```

Comment: Hi @GerhardBarnard thanks for your response. My bad, i've edited it. So if in my csv file value 3 equals empty value, then the script will change the position value 4 to be in column 3. Any advice?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard added, please see value 3 and pipe delimiter in second row

Comment: Hi @GerhardBarnard yes this csv format same, i've try from duplicate link but i still don't get it :(

Comment: ok @GerhardBarnard, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, because you do not add additional values, we simply do not use `delims`:

```
@Echo off&Setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Row=0
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (BAT0071.csv) do (
    Set /A Row+=1
    If !Row! equ 1 (
      echo %%a^|IgnoreLast
    ) else (
      echo %%a
    )
 )
)>BAT0071.tmp
move /y "BAT0071.tmp" "BAT0071.csv"
PAUSE
```

Comment: I see! so don't need to put another column in else condition. Thank you so much for your help and insight.

Comment: Ok, so you can still add additional columns if needed, it is just that currently you are not manipulating the current data, so no need to delimit on it at all, if you were to manipulate current data, then it is a different scenario.

Comment: if want to manipulate data in new column how is the mechanism? in else condition add echo %%a|%%b? (in case i want that new column have all value same with in rows value in column 2)